# connect to a localserver that is running on another server

Tags: python, web

I have server on an external hardware running at port number `162.74.90.100` and i can access all the files and terminal on it using SSH Secure Shell software.

Now i run a Python-Flask server (`127.0.0.1:5000`) on the existing server (ie. `162.74.90.100` ) which is supposed to run a website.

To access the website, I tried running the IP addresses in a browser like `162.74.90.100/127.0.0.1:5000` but it does not work.

can anyone suggest how can I access `127.0.0.1:5000` using browser? I am stuck and cannot find any relevant documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not directly. By running on 127.0.0.1 (localhost), you are *explicitly* not binding to a public IP address and are not visible to the outside world.

Your options are to:

- Use [SSH port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) to redirect traffic from your own machine to that localhost port; add `-L 5000:localhost:5000` to your `ssh` command line and access the Flask server at `http://localhost:5000`. Use this option if only you should be able to access the server.
- Use a 3rd party service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel from a public host to your Flask server.
- Use another web server serving on a public IP address forwarding connections to localhost:5000. See [*Proxy Setups*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) in the Flask deployment documentation.
- Restart the Flask server to bind to a public IP address, not 127.0.0.1. This is not recommended, as the development web server that comes bundled with Flask is not really suited for the rough world that is the public internet. You can do this by giving [`app.run()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.run) a `host` argument:

  ```
  app.run(host='162.74.90.100')
  ```

  or (using the `flask` command-line tool) using the `--host` command-line argument:

  ```
  flask run --host 162.74.90.100
  ```

  to bind to your public IP address, or use `0.0.0.0` to bind to all available IP addresses on your server. This will only work if your server is connected directly to the internet (not behind a router) and the firewall allows connections to the port; you'll need to configure the router and firewall otherwise.

Comment: i tried using `162.74.80.100`, but for some reason it did not work. So i tried using ngrok as you suggested. I am facing a problem there. When i type the following command `[root@avp ngrok_linux]# ./ngrok 80`.. I get an error which says this.
`-bash: ./ngrok: Permission denied`. i am following the commands given here [ngrok Website](https://ngrok.com/usage)

Comment: app.run(host='162.74.90.100') do you know the counterpart config for flask Blueprint ? I am working with blueprint and this is not an option for me .

Comment: @FaceBro: blueprints don't have a built-in WSGI server. You can only do this with the app. Blueprints do usually have a reference back to the app when registered, this is blueprint-dependent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters adding —host after flask run fixed my issue

Comment: @FaceBro: yes, the `flask` command line tool (added to Flask after I wrote this answer) takes command-line arguments to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are not able access your application is because you are not running it off the interface(162.74.90.100, in your case) where you need to access it from.

Since you are using a flask application, and I am assuming your run code looks something like this...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This would by default associate your application to the localhost(127.0.0.1) at port 5000. Now for the application to run on port 5000 exposed to outside world you either do this....

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='162.74.90.100')
```

or this...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I would suggest latter which runs the application off all the interfaces, hence being accessible from the outside world. Once you have made this change, you could access your application at 162.74.90.100:5000